# JavaScript - How to get the line after the second comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have a certain line I want to get from this line the word **"USA"** which is after the second comma, how can I get it?
I have a lot of such lines, I need to get a certain word that is after the second comma

```
let x = `Addr: Miami Beach, FL 321, USA, Distance: 7642 mi`;
```

Comment: you can use split  `const val = x.split(',') val[2];`

Comment: You can get USA word like this   `const val = x.split(",")[2];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply splitting the string on commas and accessing the element after the 2nd one should be enough. As long as the line does indeed contain enough commas you can do:

```js
const x = `Addr: Miami Beach, FL 321, USA, Distance: 7642 mi`;
const result = x.split(",")[2].trim();

console.log(result);
```

Please note i called `String.prototype.trim()` function simply to remove whitespace from the beginning of a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the string and get the second index from the value. Use optional chaining `.?` to avoid the error.

```js
let x = `Addr: Miami Beach, FL 321, USA, Distance: 7642 mi`;
let value = x.split(',')?.[2]?.trim() || ""
console.log(value)
```

Comment: If you introduced the usage of optional chaining why use ternary operator to trim it? you could simply call `x.split(',')?.[2]?.trim() || ""` and achieve the same

Comment: Yes, I can do this. Thanks for your suggestion!